# How to matches Java Regular expression for one word

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex

```
String str = "A";

System.out.println(str.matches("/^[A]{1}$/"));  //false
System.out.println(str.matches("/^A{1}$/"));    //false
System.out.println(str.matches("/A{1}/"));      //false
```

why they all False?

how to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need delimiters in java regex.

Remove `/`

---

If you want to check for a single character `A` anywhere in the string,your regex would be `A`

If you want to check for the **only** single character `A` in string,use `^A$`

Answer (score 1):

In Java regexes you don't need

1. Regex delimiters `/`
2. Anchors `^` and `$` when you use the `matches()` method. `matches()` tries to match the regex against the complete string. If you want to find a pattern anywhere in the string, you need the `find()` method.
3. and in all regex flavours `{1}` is superfluous

So

```
System.out.println(str.matches("A"));
```

Would be the correct one.